# View always null in Windows Manager

Tags: android-view

I have a BroadcastReceiver for incoming calls and on getting incoming calls I want to inflate a view.

But when I try to removeview when call state is IDLE, app crash with:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null

My code:

```
String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
         new HttpAsyncTask().execute();
                                                            }
 if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {
       removeview();
    }
```

Inside onPostExecute I call

```
showview();
```

And this is my method:

```
public void showview(){

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
    params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;

    wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
    txtIncomingnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtviewoncall);
    txtIncomingnumber.setText("TEST");
    wm.addView(view, params);

}

public void removeview(){


        wm.removeView(view);


}
```